# How do I install a library such as opencv permanently in Colab when building it from source?

Tags: python, opencv, google-colaboratory

I have to try running code of a particular project on github in colab but it seems that it requires opencv built from source to run without producing errors. Building opencv on colab takes around 3 hours for me so i am looking for ways to install it permanently on colab. Is it possible to install it on google drive? If yes, then how do i make opencv installed on drive to be "visible" to code running on colab?

Comment: Have you tried `!pip install opencv`

Answer (score 0):

Kindly follow below steps: 
***1. Google authentication using your gmail ID:***

```
!apt-get install -y -qq software-properties-common python-software-properties module-init-tools
!add-apt-repository -y ppa:alessandro-strada/ppa 2>&1 > /dev/null
!apt-get update -qq 2>&1 > /dev/null
!apt-get -y install -qq google-drive-ocamlfuse fuse
from google.colab import auth
auth.authenticate_user()
from oauth2client.client import GoogleCredentials
creds = GoogleCredentials.get_application_default()
import getpass
!google-drive-ocamlfuse -headless -id={creds.client_id} -secret={creds.client_secret} < /dev/null 2>&1 | grep URL
vcode = getpass.getpass()
!echo {vcode} | google-drive-ocamlfuse -headless -id={creds.client_id} -secret={creds.client_secret}
```

***2. Create drive for your operation:***

```
!mkdir -p drive
!google-drive-ocamlfuse drive
```

***3. If not installed install opencv lib or else import opencv***

```
import cv2
```

Comment: Shoud i place source files(for installation) in drive and then run cmake? Can i set the CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX to a folder in drive?

Comment: Yes, you should place source required for installation in drive.